A general formula for a tricky combinatorics problem.
I am struggling to find a general solution to the following combinatorial problem.
Assume we have some decimal integer of length $n$ which contains all possible digits from 0 to 9 at least once (obviously, for $n < 10$ no such numbers exist). Let's denote these 10 distinct digits with letters from A to J in order of their first occurrence in that number. So for $n = 10$, this number must have the form ABCDEFGHIJ, which is the only digit pattern of length 10 that contains all 10 different digits. For longer integers, different patterns are possible, for example ABBCDEFGHIJ is not the same as ABCBDEFGHIJ. The total number of such patterns of length $n$ is given by $\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{}{n}{10}$ = StirlingS2$(n,10)$.
Now to my problem. The sum of all digits A+B+...+J = 45, which means that all numbers of the form ABCDEFGHIJ have their sum of digits divisible by 9, hence they are themselves divisible by 3. We say that the pattern ABCDEFGHIJ is identically divisible by 3 (and 9), meaning that it is divisible independently of the values we choose for the digits A, B,... Therefore none of the $9\cdot9!=3265920$ numbers with this digit pattern can be a prime.
What I am interested in is the number of digit patterns that are identically divisible by 3 as a function of $n$, which becomes quite nontrivial as the patterns get longer. Let's call this function $F(n)$. We already know that $F(10)=1$, and it is easy to show that $F(11)=F(12)=0$. Then, at $n=13$, patterns such as ABCBDEFGBHIBJ start appearing in which all 10 digits are present, and the remaining 3 digits are the same. In other words, one of the digits occurs 4 times and all others just once. Here the sum of digits equals 45+3$\cdot$B, making all such patterns identically divisible by 3. Since I can choose 4 equal digits out of the 13 available in $\binom{13}{4}$ different ways, $F(13) = \binom{13}{4} = 715$. Then $F(14)=F(15)=0$, but at $n=16$, I have two possibilities: patterns with two digits occurring 4 times each and all others exactly once or one digit occurring 7 times and all others exactly once. In both cases I get divisibility by 3, hence $F(16) = \binom{16}{7} + \frac{1}{2}\binom{16}{4}\binom{12}{4} = 461890$. Then, again, $F(17)=F(18)=0$, and $F(19) = \binom{19}{10} + \binom{19}{7}\binom{12}{4} + \frac{1}{3!}\binom{19}{4}\binom{15}{4}\binom{11}{4} = 316025138$. Starting from $n=20$, all 10 distinct digits can occur exactly twice each in the pattern, which results in $F(20)=\prod_{i=1}^9(2i+1)=654729075$. Then, $F(21)=0$, $F(22) = \binom{22}{13} + \binom{22}{10}\binom{12}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\binom{22}{7}\binom{15}{7} + \frac{1}{2}\binom{22}{7}\binom{15}{4}\binom{11}{4} + \frac{1}{4!}\binom{22}{4}\binom{18}{4}\binom{14}{4}\binom{10}{4} = 235335069035$, $F(23)=\binom{23}{5}\prod_{i=1}^8(2i+1)=1159525191825$, and so on. We see that $F(n)$ has a nonzero value whenever $n$ can be written down as $n=10p+3q$ for some $p\geq1$ and $q\geq0$. Starting from $n=28$, any integer can be represented in this way, and starting from $n=40$ such representations are not unique, since 40=10$\cdot$4 or 40=10$\cdot$1+3$\cdot$10.
So to reformulate this problem shorter, I am looking for the number of $n$-letter words over a 10-letter alphabet (all 10 letters must be present at least once) such that after dropping all possible complete subsets of 10 distinct letters, the remaining letters all occur a number of times that is divisible by 3.
Do you think there might be a way of writing some general formula for $F(n)$ that would take care of all these situations also for larger $n$?

I wouldn't use the word "identically" this way. It gives the wrong impression, usually implying some sort of equivalence rather than what you mean here. I think the only words you can get which satisfy your definition are  ones where every letter occurs an equal number of times.

If you want to allow starting zero digits, as your counts imply, don't call what you are seeking "decimal integers," call them "decimal strings."

I do not allow starting zero digits. Otherwise it would be $10!$ numbers and not $9\cdot9!$ as I wrote.

The word "identically" means exactly that. E.g. "identically equal" means equal for any possible values of the variables. Therefore "identically divisible" means divisible for any possible values of the variables.

I always assume $1 \leq A \leq 9$ but $0 \leq B \leq 9$ etc. This is irrelevant for the question, though, as I am interested in the number of patterns and not in the number of integers themselves. I told this just to motivate the problem so that it doesn't look totally artificial.

Regarding examples for the usage of "identically divisible", see, for instance, arXiv:1403.5937 or arXiv:2003.09593.

"I think the only words you can get which satisfy your definition are ones where every letter occurs an equal number of times." This is clearly wrong, and I gave plenty of examples to illustrate that. In the word ABCBDEFGBHIBJ, the sum of digits is 45+3B, hence it is divisible by 3. Here B occurs 4 times but all other digits just once.

$f(x)$ is identically divisible by $q$ means the same as $f(x) \equiv 0$ (mod $q$) (in the sence of identically equal, i.e. equal for any possible value of $x$). In my example, the integer ABCDEFGHIJ is essentially an integer-valued function of 10 variables A,B,...,J. In this respect, there is no mistake in saying that it is identically divisible by 3 in the sense ABCDEFGHIJ $\equiv$ 0 (mod 3).

I got a slightly different value of $F(19)=316025138$.

@ploosu2 - I understood my mistake. The factor 1/2 in front of $\binom{19}{7}\binom{12}{4}$ was not necessary because the indices 7 and 4 are not equal. Using your calculated table, I will try to generalize these formulas, maybe something useful comes out.

@Vosoni Great! One could also try to change the base $B=10$. For $B=2$ I found this: https://oeis.org/A024494 (except the second value $0$ instead of $2$). I'm trying to verify that by diagonalizing the matrix but it's quite cumbersome. The eigenvalues seem to have some structure. For $B=2$ they are $2$ times the third roots of unity, the sixth roots of unity and $0$.

Eigenvalues for $B=10$: https://www.online-python.com/jd6KTk7zbu

For base 2 it is trivial because there is no analog of A+B+...+J = 45. All integers except repunits contain all possible distinct digits (which is 2) and then it's simple. But in other bases it can be interesting. The divisibility rule by  3 exists because 3 is a divisor of $b-1=9$. Choose any base $b$ such that the sum of all possible digit values is divisible by a nontrivial divisor of $b-1$, and that's where things get interesting.

Oh right, if we consider the original problem. I was only focusing on counting the patterns.

The patterns you want to count should be different in different bases because mod 3 is specific to base 10. So in other bases your algorithm should be modified to other divisors, sometimes maybe several of them.

I see, but if we forget the original problem and try to just solve it with that pattern. And then use that solution only for the case $B=10$.

I understand that the question was closed because it was answered, but why does it say that it lacks details or clarity? What other details could one want here?

Let's consider the finite automaton where a state is a $3$-tuple recording the number of letters whose appearance count is $0, 1$ and $2$ modulo $3$.
For example the string AABCBDEFGBBGG will have state $(1, 5, 1)$ since

there is $1$ letter (G) whose count ($3$) is $0 \pmod 3$
there are $5$ letters (B, C, D, E, F) whose count is $1 \pmod 3$
there is $1$ letter (A) whose count ($2$) is $2 \pmod 3$

Then the (weighted) transitions between these states are as follows. From the state $(c_0, c_1, c_2)$ we can, by getting a letter that's already seen, move to

$(c_0-1, c_1+1, c_2)$ in $c_0$ ways
$(c_0, c_1-1, c_2+1)$ in $c_1$ ways
$(c_0+1, c_1, c_2-1)$ in $c_2$ ways

Or we can get a new letter (only in one way since assuming the alphabetical ordering) and transition to the state

$(c_0, c_1+1, c_2)$ if $c_0+c_1+c_2<10$.

We start from the state $(0,0,0)$ and the favourable end states are $(10, 0, 0), (0,10,0)$ and $(0,0,10)$. We could write this as a transition matrix and get the answer by taking the $n$th power of the matrix. But I wrote a Python code with dictionaries that calculates it iteratively.
from collections import defaultdict

#B = base
def F(n, B=10):
    g = defaultdict(int)
    g[(0, 0, 0)] = 1
    for r in range(n):
        g2 = defaultdict(int)
        for key in g:
            w = g[key]
            c0,c1,c2 = key
            #letter already seen comes
            if c0>0: g2[(c0-1,c1+1,c2)] += c0*w
            if c1>0: g2[(c0,c1-1,c2+1)] += c1*w
            if c2>0: g2[(c0+1,c1,c2-1)] += c2*w
            #a new letter comes, it has just one choice (the next one)
            if c0+c1+c2<B: g2[(c0, c1+1, c2)] += w
        g = g2
    return g[(B, 0, 0)]+g[(0, B, 0)]+g[(0, 0, B)]


for n in range(100):
    print ("%d: %d" %(n,F(n)))

The first few values this produces:
0: 0
1: 0
2: 0
3: 0
4: 0
5: 0
6: 0
7: 0
8: 0
9: 0
10: 1
11: 0
12: 0
13: 715
14: 0
15: 0
16: 461890
17: 0
18: 0
19: 316025138
20: 654729075
21: 0
22: 235335069035
23: 1159525191825
24: 0
25: 190096345621325
26: 1410479572627125
27: 0
28: 164505143582062140
29: 1500148682523465975
30: 1208883745669600000
31: 150262413817995558300
32: 1511851886809308094050
33: 3297834858186668800000
34: 142768878934930510829061
35: 1493307979098723716398470
36: 5578287662622750275200000
37: 139275443218501203114424495
38: 1467569446474312523663431110
39: 7620213108459427953917440000
40: 138036773428997400941782302790
41: 1444286170987444915914239025570
42: 9270890895222511472427590080000
43: 137938295354131106531938899562918
44: 1426525184156032566548211835538973
45: 10532935787461649812044959836672000
46: 138310695173779568351408544986270255
47: 1414383640357604138277688932679130751
48: 11469266383481372006039769457835648000
49: 138793818945326799813778573974096862385
50: 1406816015944160161945541897426523108051
51: 12153698409869449715968341500839554560000
52: 139223613302583567777732771624302521659680
53: 1402526136405518185997859474937162339307745
54: 12651177005004045446968736645339227098272000
55: 139546719256789852366258448964037927049151120
56: 1400364603283257023923349192640511200661866180
57: 13012665232637050856099010620191739686393088000
58: 139763814662329499908137748617533162573044410921
59: 1399461924252284187421689914660751569248268407260

Writing out the transition matrix, its eigenvalues have a nice pattern:

Same pattern holds for other $B$ too. Seems to be the Eisenstein integers intersected with the triangle $(B, 0), (-\frac{B}{2}, h), (-\frac{B}{2}, -h)$ where $h = \frac{\sqrt{3}B}{2}$. And the multiplicities grow tetrahedrally from the origin:

All the eigenvalues are of the form $\lambda = (a+b\omega)$ where $\omega = e^{2\pi i/3}$ and $a,b$ are integers. Since $\omega^2 = -\omega - 1$ we have
$$
(a+b\omega)^n = \sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \right\rfloor} \binom{n}{3j}a^{n-3j}b^{3j}
- \sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{n-2}{3} \right\rfloor} \binom{n}{3j+2}a^{n-3j-2}b^{3j+2} + \omega \cdot \text{ something }
$$
We are so lucky that when diagonalizing the matrix and then calculating the coefficient of $\lambda^n$ it turns out to always be a rational number. So we dont care about the $\omega$ part in the above (in fact they must cancel out since the result is a rational integer). Here are the coefficients $c_{a,b}$ as Python dictionary
{(10, 0): 1, (9, 0): -10, (9, 1): 0, (8, -1): 0, (8, 0): 135, (8, 1): -90, (7, -1): -90, (8, 2): 0, (6, -2): 0, (7, 1): 1080, (6, -1): 1080, (7, 2): -360, (5, -2): -360, (7, 3): 120, (4, -3): 120, (6, 2): 3780, (4, -2): 3780, (6, 3): -840, (3, -3): -840, (6, 4): 0, (2, -4): 0, (5, 3): 7560, (2, -3): 7560, (5, 4): -1260, (1, -4): -1260, (5, 5): 0, (0, -5): 0, (4, 4): 9450, (0, -4): 9450, (4, 5): -1260, (-1, -5): -1260, (4, 6): 210, (-2, -6): 210, (3, 5): 7560, (-2, -5): 7560, (3, 6): -840, (-3, -6): -840, (3, 7): 0, (-4, -7): 0, (2, 6): 3780, (-4, -6): 3780, (2, 7): -360, (-5, -7): -360, (2, 8): 0, (-6, -8): 0, (1, 7): 1080, (-6, -7): 1080, (1, 8): -90, (-7, -8): -90, (1, 9): 10, (-8, -9): 10, (0, 8): 135, (-1, 6): 1080, (-2, 4): 3780, (-3, 2): 7560, (-4, 0): 9450, (-5, -2): 7560, (-6, -4): 3780, (-7, -6): 1080, (-8, -8): 135, (0, 9): -10, (-1, 7): -90, (-2, 5): -360, (-3, 3): -840, (-4, 1): -1260, (-5, -1): -1260, (-6, -3): -840, (-7, -5): -360, (-8, -7): -90, (-9, -9): -10, (0, 10): 0, (-1, 8): 0, (-2, 6): 45, (-3, 4): 0, (-4, 2): 0, (-5, 0): 252, (-6, -2): 0, (-7, -4): 0, (-8, -6): 45, (-9, -8): 0, (-10, -10): 0, (7, 0): -990, (6, 0): 4950, (6, 1): -7560, (5, -1): -7560, (5, 0): -12852, (5, 1): 31500, (4, -1): 31500, (5, 2): -22680, (3, -2): -22680, (4, 1): -79380, (3, -1): -79380, (4, 2): 80010, (2, -2): 80010, (4, 3): -36540, (1, -3): -36540, (3, 2): -166320, (1, -2): -166320, (3, 3): 107100, (0, -3): 107100, (3, 4): -37800, (-1, -4): -37800, (2, 3): -166320, (-1, -3): -166320, (2, 4): 80010, (-2, -4): 80010, (2, 5): -22680, (-3, -5): -22680, (1, 4): -79380, (-3, -4): -79380, (1, 5): 31500, (-4, -5): 31500, (1, 6): -7200, (-5, -6): -7200, (0, 5): -12852, (-1, 3): -79380, (-2, 1): -166320, (-3, -1): -166320, (-4, -3): -79380, (-5, -5): -12852, (0, 6): 4950, (-1, 4): 31500, (-2, 2): 80010, (-3, 0): 107100, (-4, -2): 80010, (-5, -4): 31500, (-6, -6): 4950, (0, 7): -1080, (-1, 5): -7560, (-2, 3): -21840, (-3, 1): -37800, (-4, -1): -37800, (-5, -3): -21840, (-6, -5): -7560, (-7, -7): -1080, (4, 0): 6930, (3, 0): 75060, (3, 1): 90720, (2, -1): 90720, (2, 0): -253125, (2, 1): 65160, (1, -1): 65160, (2, 2): 154980, (0, -2): 154980, (1, 1): -339930, (0, -1): -339930, (1, 2): 65160, (-1, -2): 65160, (1, 3): 93240, (-2, -3): 93240, (0, 2): -253125, (-1, 0): -339930, (-2, -2): -253125, (0, 3): 75060, (-1, 1): 65160, (-2, -1): 65160, (-3, -3): 75060, (0, 4): 5670, (-1, 2): 90720, (-2, 0): 158130, (-3, -2): 90720, (-4, -4): 5670, (1, 0): 324150, (0, 0): -11697, (0, 1): 319950, (-1, -1): 319950}
I've taken out a denominator $10! 3^9$ from them. The formula then reads
$$
\frac{1}{10! 3^9} \sum_{a,b} c_{a,b} \left( \sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \right\rfloor} \binom{n}{3j}a^{n-3j}b^{3j}
- \sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{n-2}{3} \right\rfloor} \binom{n}{3j+2}a^{n-3j-2}b^{3j+2} \right)
$$

This is very helpful, thank you. It is great to have these numbers calculated. I still wonder if there is any systematics behind them that would let us write them as some analytical expressions, e.g. in terms of binomial coefficients. Looks doubtful.

In your 3rd bullet point, shouldn't it be $(c_0+1,c_1,c_2-1)$ instead? In your code it is correct.

Yes, fixed that. Thanks for pointing that out.

@Vosoni I added a picture of the eigenvalues for $B=10$. Certainly a nice pattern there :D

I think there's hope for deriving a formula programmatically since all the eigenvalues are in the field $\mathbb{Q}[ \omega_3 ]$ and Sage manages to Jordan decompose the matrix. But then putting the eigenvalues to power $n$ appears to be a problem...

What is plotted on your horizontal axis?

The points are the eigenvalues of the transition matrix as complex numbers, so the x-axis is the real part. I now have a way to generate a formula that's a sum over the eigenvalues. But the calculation for $B=10$ is taking too long...

This looks more systematic and beautiful than I initially imagined. I thought it would be a huge list of special cases. As I understand, the cases like n=40 where I expected anomalies would just appear naturally here.

The formula now finished. Well it is kind of huge :D. Don't know if it simplifies somehow. For approximation we could take only the more significant terms. Here's a picture how the coefficients look: https://www.desmos.com/3d/f4wofclq5p and the formula as Python code: https://www.online-python.com/4Rm1nfk3CH

Wow! That is impressive.

Are $a$ and $b$ the values given in brackets?

Yes, the dictionary has keys $(a,b)$ mapped to their coefficients. And we sum over all the keys.
